# Azure appservice for containers and managed service identity MSI support not working

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a docker image of an aspnetcore application which i deploy to an instance of an azure appservice for containers on a linux app plan.

The moment i enable MSI - even though i am not using it - the website stops serving.

I am going to write sample apps to figure out further but wondered if anyone has any insight on what the problem could be ?

(I know there are lots of reasons it could be. I suppose what im asking is - unless the application is accessing another azure resource MSI should not be a factor, right?). And why would MSI stop the app from working when it works without it enabled?

The logs seem to show an attempt to contact appsvc/msitokenservice before failing

Answer (score 0):

It appears a question of a similar nature has already been answered:

[Azure App Service stops working after enabling Managed Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59284488/azure-app-service-stops-working-after-enabling-managed-identity)

Comment: shame.  i am rubbish at searching.  have spent the last few days at this.  will look deeper and come back, but thanks for now

Comment: i still cant seem to get this to work.  I had previously looked at the kudu environment, but the MSI_* values are not visible to me but states that 'they will be visible to the application'

Comment: @Kam same here, did you find a solution?

Comment: @Robar i think this is how it is supposed to work.  You dont need to see and access the values as the environment takes care of it for you. however, i believe my web app is trying to access stuff it is not allowed to by the new MSI.  Try a vanilla web app.  Or comment out behaviour until you can at least find out which resource is causing an issue then try assigning policy/iam to that resource to solve your issue

Comment: @Kam well thanks for the hint. I'll give it a try. We currently using CosmosDb and Azure Storage, maybe those cause the trouble, even though we are accessing them with connection strings and not via AAD/MSI.

Comment: @Robar exactly what didnt make sense to me neither.  Im accessing things through connection string.  But i also admit to not having read in depth on msi. I still need to dig a little deeper on this myself but my aim was to get things running for now and gold plate later.  Do let me know if you find anything though.  Im aiming to take a look over christmas myself

Comment: am tracking this convo whch seems to be the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65451162/using-azure-web-app-for-containers-with-managed-identity